# Default writing place for MySQL DBs with Docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following node in my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
mysql:
    image: mariadb:latest
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
    environment:
          - MYSQL_USER=bla
          - MYSQL_PASSWORD=blubb
          - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=blubb
          - MYSQL_DATABASE=blubb
    volumes:
      - ./docker/data:/data
      - ./docker/builds/mysql/my.cnf:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
      - ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

See the very last line: `- ./docker/mysql:/var/lib/mysql`. 
If I put this line there, my Database gets persistent on my HDD. If I leave it out, will Docker write files to an invisible folder on its $HOME (i.e. /home/user/xxx/.docker/container/mysql/whatever)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is a system-controlled directory under `/var/lib/docker`.  If you're in a Docker Toolbox or Docker Machine environment where Docker runs under a VM, that directory path is inside the VM.  Docker controls that directory tree, in some places in complicated ways, and you generally shouldn't be doing anything directly inside of it.

In turn, this default happens because the MySQL Dockerfile contains the line `VOLUME ["/var/lib/mysql"]`, which causes Docker to create that storage automatically.  Otherwise, the only persistent storage is what's explicitly declared with `docker run -v` or the `volumes:` section.

---